# Capasitive Touch screen not propogatinng events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, touch

```
I have a WPF application which implements drag and drop operations. Once i created any window or message box from the Dropped event , it is to getting any events say mouse down or preview mouse down etc.

private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
          DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, "DropData", DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

private void Button_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(" dropped data on event");
}
```

The problem is

When it run this sample in CAPASITIVE TOUCH SCREEN i am not able to click on the MESSAGE BOX buttons (OK Or CANCEL )

Any help will be appreciated!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had done a work around by using a thread on drop event.